# Problema con programa que haga la tabla de multiplicar del 5

Tags: php

buenas ando haciendo un programa con que haga la tabla de multiplicar del 5 pero ocupo que se me despliegue en la pantalla así al momento de poner echo no me deja imprimir los caracteres me arroja los números de 5 en 5 pero no me arroja  los caracteres del echo no se a que se deba

> ```
> 5 x 1 = 5
> 5 x 2 = 10
> 5 x 1 = 15
> ```

Este es mi código:

```
    <?php
echo"<table BORDER='1'>";

echo"
<tr>
<td colspan=7 align=center> TABLA  DEL 5</td>
</tr> 
 <td> 5 x 1 </td>
<td> 5 x 2</td>
<td> 5 x 3</td>
<td> 5 x 4</td>
<td> 5 x 5</td>
<td> 5 x 6</td>
<td> 5 x 7</td>
<td> 5 x 8</td>
<td> 5 x 9</td>
<td> 5 x 10</td>
</tr>
</table>";



$a=1;
$b=5;
$resultado;
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
    $resultado= $i * 5;

     echo "Las tabla de multiplicar del 5 es " $b. ."*".  $a.  ".=."  $resultado;




}


?>
```

Comment: El punto deberia estar antes de la variable $b y no despues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la tabla de multiplicar del 5 y tener a su vez un código mas ordenado, primero deberías sacar el titulo del ciclo for si no se esta imprimiendo en cada iteración; además no veo necesidad de la variable $a y por último tu for debería inciar desde cero por lo demás esta bien; coompruebalo con el ejemplo que te pongo

```
<?php
echo "Las tabla de multiplicar del 5 es";
$b=5; $resultado;
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
  echo $b*$i.PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Ahora si quieres que a lado de cada resultado aparezca la operación que se esta haciendo para que tenga mas la forma de tabla de multiplicar, haz lo siguiente

```
<?php
echo "Las tabla de multiplicar del 5 es";
$a=1; $b=5; $resultado;
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
  echo "$b * $i = ".$b*$i.PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

> Del modo anterior tienes el resultado deseado pero con un código mas
>   ordenado además de que con PHP_EOL tienes saltos de línea también;
>   todo eso en un código mas limpio

Answer (score 1):

Corrigiendo tu error, quedaría tu programa de la siguiente manera:

El error esta en la concatenación de tu `echo` en el `for`

```
echo"";

echo" TABLA DEL 5 5 x 1 5 x 2 5 x 3 5 x 4 5 x 5 5 x 6 5 x 7 5 x 8 5 x 9 5 x 10 \n\n";

$a=1; $b=5; $resultado; for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { 
    $resultado= $i * 5;
    echo "Las tabla de multiplicar del 5 es ". $b ."*". $a .  "=".$resultado."\n";
}
```

Comment: Solo te falto ver que hay variables que no se están utilizando , en el caso de la variable $a y también que al momento de hacer el echo esta imprimiendo de forma incorrecta el numero por el que esta multiplicando.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo de forma correcta queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
echo "TABLA DEL 5 5 x 1 5 x 2 5 x 3 5 x 4 5 x 5 5 x 6 5 x 7 5 x 8 5 x 9 5 x 10 <br>";
$b=5; $resultado; 
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { 
 $resultado = $i * $b;
 echo "Las tabla de multiplicar del 5 es ".$b."*".$i." = ".$resultado."<br>";
}
?>
```

La variable `$a` desaparece ya que no la necesitas, para realizar las operaciones unicamente necesitas `$b` y la variable `$i` que se encuentra dentro del `for` y al imprimir los datos remplace la variable `$a` por la `$i` ya que es la variable que se esta aumentando en cada ciclo y por ultimo en la variable `$resultado` cambie el numero `5` por la variable `$b` ya que no estabas haciendo uso de las variables que tenias declaradas.

Answer (score 1):

Para generar una tabla puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
<?php
// Ingresa el numero de tabla a multiplicar
$tabla = 5;

echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 width=200";
echo "<tr><th colspan=5> Tabla del $tabla </th></tr>";

// Iteracion para generar la Tabla
 for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) 
 {
   echo "<tr><td align=center>$tabla</td>
             <td align=center>x</td>
             <td align=center>$i</td>
             <td align=center>=</td>
             <td align=center> ". $tabla*$i . "</td>
         </tr>";
 }
 echo "</table> <br/>";
?>
```

Puedes testearlo [aquí](http://phptester.net/)

Consultar otros ejemplos: [Pagina](http://elticus.com/?contenido=111)